# How to change Model Binding Name

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an InputModel like this:

```
public class InputModel{
     public string SmtpId{get;set;}
}
```

But what I really want is to the ModelBinder to bind to `smtp-id` as that is how the data arrives from SendGrid.

Is this possible?

This is what is being posted:

```
 {
    "email":"john.doe@sendgrid.com",
    "timestamp": 1337197600,
    "smtp-id":"<4FB4041F.6080505@sendgrid.com>",
    "sg_event_id":"sendgrid_internal_event_id",
    "sg_message_id":"sendgrid_internal_message_id",
    "event": "processed"
  },
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can decorate your property with the `JsonProperty` attribute like this:

```
public class InputModel{
    [JsonProperty("first_name")]
    public string FirstName{get;set;}
}
```

It will work for serialization and deserialization.

Comment: FYI: ASP.NET Core utilizes JSON.NET (Newtonsoft.Json package) for JSON serialization/deserialization. So, for anything JSON related, you can consult that documentation.

Comment: Only it doesn't appear to be used by the ModelBinder, as it is not still binding to the Model even using that Attribute.

Comment: How *are* you binding your `InputModel`? If you're using a standard form encoding, for example, it's not going to be JSON and so this answer will not apply.

Comment: Updated question to include sample

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET Core 3.0 onwards uses System.Text.Json instead of Newtonsoft.Json (a.k.a. Json.NET) by default, so you should use the `JsonPropertyName` attribute:

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

public class InputModel
{
   [JsonPropertyName("smtp-id")]
   public string SmtpId { get; set; }
}
```

If you still want to use Newtonsoft.Json, you have to:

1. Install the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson package

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson
```

2. Set Newtonsoft.Json as the default input/output formatter in Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
   ...

   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
      services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
      ...
   }

   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isssue is being tracked here: [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7824#issuecomment-391839414)

It appears this will be updated in a future version.  In the meantime, this works:

`[ModelBinder(Name = "smtp-id")]`